# Explicitly unwrapping an assignment to an optional property in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, option-type

I saw this while reviewing Swift 2.2 code and I am puzzled:

```
(myVar?.aProperty=aValue)!
```

where aValue is not an optional.

The result of this expression is not stored anywhere, hence why put a ! at the end?  Also, what is the terminology for this type of expression?

Comment: IMO, you're right. Expression result is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a little difference, when used in a closure.

```
let closure1 = {
    aVar?.aProperty = aValue
}
let closure2 = {
    (aVar?.aProperty = aValue)!
}
```

Swift infers `closure1`'s type as `()->Optional<()>`, aka `()->Void?`. Which is not the same as `()->Void`. So, `closure1` cannot be passed to a parameter claiming `()->Void`.

So, if you want to make the closure's type `()->Void`, you may need to write something like this:

```
let closure1 = {
    _ = aVar?.aProperty = aValue
}
```

Or this:

```
let closure1 = {
    aVar?.aProperty = aValue
    return
}
```

Or else:

```
let closure1 = {
    (aVar?.aProperty = aValue)!
}
```

And now, you can write something like this:

```
let closure1: ()->Void = {
    aVar?.aProperty = aValue
}
```

But, in old, old Swift, the last example did not compile.

---

If you find that code in a completely different context than making a closure, I cannot guess what the purpose is.

Comment: Good explanation.  However the code was embedded in a func that returned no value.